# Пропали все картинки

Tags: графика

Здраствуйте!
После установки плагина пропали все картинки на сайте http://english-from-england.ru
Новые загруженные картинки тоже пропадают.
Действия котрые не помогли:
1.Бекапы
2.Установка сохранненой базы
3. Отключение плагинов
4. Замена темы
Плагин wp-optimize, его основное предназначение удаление автоматически спам комментов,неподтвержденных комментов,оптимизация базы данных. Вот после активации вроде бы все работало, но все картинки исчезли. Я сразу же обратилась за бэкапом,но ничего не восстановилось
поверхностный анализ показал, что при запросе картинок  идет 301 редирект
Спасибо

Comment: т.е. если даже в url `правильный` адрес картинки ввести, то все-равно редирект? Кстати, непонятно какие именно картинки, на главной и далее вроде ничего такого незаметно?

Comment: анализ показал, что при запросе картинок (напр. http://english-from-england.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/english-from-england.ru78-300x200.jpg) идет 301 редирект на страницу (http://english-from-england.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/english-from-england.ru78-300x200.jpg/ - слеш в конце).
 как исправить?

Comment: `english-from-england.ru78-300x200.jpg` а у вас точно есть такая картинка? Название чуть более чем странное, может быть так: `english-from-england.ru/78-300x200.jpg` т.е. где-то слеш потерярли.

Comment: Gerome,ссылку картинки я скопировала у себя на странице и проверила ее например на этом ресурсе  http://www.bertal.ru/, показывает редирект 301 . У меня пропали все картинки на сайте,тех поддержка написала При отрытии вашего сайта происходят множественные ошибки в javascript, анализ подобных ошибок не может быть произведен со стороны технической поддержки
Помогите

Comment: Покажите "Постоянную ссылку на результат" от сюда http://www.bertal.ru

Comment: Вот ссылка на результат:
http://www.bertal.ru/index.php?a831761/english-from-england.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/ng2_small.png#h

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.0.6
Date: Sun, 23 Jun 2013 19:26:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.18
X-Pingback: http://english-from-england.ru/xmlrpc.php
Location: http://english-from-england.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/ng2_small.png/
Content-Length: 0

Спасибо

Comment: http://english-from-england.ru/wp-content/uploads/icons/5bfa8cbdc4c2-40x45.png работает нормально, все-же перепроверьте что файлы есть и их регистр совпадает с регистром в url. а вообще 301 вместо 404, не самая лучшая идея.